# Can g++ detect losing significant bits?

Tags: g++

Can g++ detect losing significant bits?

```
int main()
{
unsigned long l = 0x123456789abcd;
unsigned int i  = 0x12345678;

unsigned short s1 = l;
unsigned short s2 = i;

return (s1 + s2);
}
```

g++ -Wall -Wextra foo.cpp

// No warnings

gcc version 4.4.6

Answer (score 0):

Despite its unambigous name, "-Wall" does not enable all warnings. '-Wconversion' will notify you of truncating conversions. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: g++ -Wconversion foo.cpp